# Jetbrains "tag.class" live template

Tags: html, jetbrains-ide, live-templates

Currently, while using one of `JetBrain's IDE` on an `HTML` file, if you type something like `div.row` and hit `TAB`, it will print the following:

```
<div class="row"></div>
```

I would like to edit the live template in order to add an `HTML` comment after the closing TAG, with the name of the TAG; I'd like to get something like:

```
<div class="row"></div><!-- row -->
```

Do you know the name of the proper live template to edit, I was not able to find it in `Setting/Editor/Live Templates`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Settings | Editor | Emmet | HTML`, Filters enabled by default/Comment tags should do the thing

Comment: thanks, this answer to my question. do you know how I can edit it further (e.g, add some rules to add details to comment)

Comment: it's Emmet 'comment tag' filter (http://docs.emmet.io/filters/, Comment tags: c). Unfortunately there is no way to modify its output.

Comment: If you like to modify live templates used for certain abbreviations, this can be done in Setting/Editor/Live Templates/ZenHTML